# Concatenation of languages - Basics

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar

Just trying to understand a homework problem in my theory of computation class:
$L_1 = (a^nb^n: n > 0)$ and
$L_2 = (c^n: n > 0)$
List the concatenation of $L_1L_2$ where $n = 2$.

I can find lots of examples of basic concatenation (with no powers). So $L_1L_2$ would be: $\{ac,bc\}$

At a guess for $n=2\quad L_1L_2$ = $\{ac,bc,aacc,bbcc\}$.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

When $n=2$, you get $w_1 = aabb$ and $w_2 = cc$, concatenating those would give you $aabbcc$. Powers here show how many of a particular element you have so $a^2$ is just $aa$.